# Jquery masonry is not resizing width properly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, image, jquery-masonry

I have an angularjs app. All of the grid elements in my container contain images. I have a reduce size function that reduces the image width and height to 50%. The height if the JQuery Masonry grid elements adjust fine but the width stays the same. Here is the code for the elements:

```
    <div id="part-one" class="work">
        <div class="box"><img class='answer123' src="http://payload295.cargocollective.com/1/16/530244/8200024/prt_200x160_1404837059.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box "><img class='answer123' src="http://payload295.cargocollective.com/1/16/530244/8200024/prt_200x160_1404837059.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box"><img class='answer123' src="http://payload295.cargocollective.com/1/16/530244/8200024/prt_200x160_1404837059.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my reduce size function that is triggered on a button click:

```
$scope.reduceSize = function(){
    $(".answer123").width("50%")
    $(".answer123").height("50%");
}
```

Here is how I initialize the container:

```
    var $container = $('.work');     
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.box',
            columnWidth:  $(".answer123")              
         });
    });
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see you calling the function reducesize. It looks like you are declaring it. Add $scope.reduceSize(); to your code to trigger the function.

Comment: I am calling it in a button click. The function does get triggered. It reduces the size of the images correctly but for some reason it is not reducing the width of the container.